# Vertically align content within container with auto height and min-height defined

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically center content within HTML container that has next properties:

```
height: auto;
min-height: 50%;
```

I tried different alignment techniques without success. For example:

- table: http://jsfiddle.net/7g461sne/
- ghost element: http://jsfiddle.net/7g461sne/1/

Could you advice how to vertically center content in a such container? I'm interested in pure HTML/CSS solution.

Comment: Solution is here for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Comment: What solution do you exactly mean? Please pay attention on the specific of my question - container has "auto" height as well as defined min-height.

Answer (score 1):

First I am going with the table structure. Update your CSS like below.

```
 .main-container {
border: 1px solid;
height: auto;
min-height: 50%; /* important */
display:table;
width:100%;
}

.child-container {
display: inline-table;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.content {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7g461sne/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work in Firefox - min-height is ignored. It relates to this issue: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the **css**:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container {
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50%; /* important */
    width:100%;
}

.child-container {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please see the updated [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6qugghe/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work in Firefox - min-height is ignored. It relates to this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866.

Comment: You can use jQuery for min-height. **See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gaj7m8fm/)**.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm interested in pure HTML/CSS solution (updated the question). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/theharsh/k7uwnnfb/**

You should try the CSS3 technique if IE8 or below is not the issue there.
Element can be set vertically centered without the concern of Height.

HTML :

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="vcenter">
        Yo! This is Centered !
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.box{
   height:200px;
   background:tomato;
   color:#fff;
   width:200px;
}
.vcenter{
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    background:purple;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: You use fixed height on "box" element. In my case it has height "auto" and min-height. Your solution does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/k7uwnnfb/1/.

Comment: Does child element has fixed height ?

Comment: No, child element does not have fixed height.